# Mixing Swing GUI components and JOGL

Tags: java, user-interface, jogl

How does one go about adding `JButton`s among various other Swing GUI components inside a JOGL canvas? Is it even possible? Is it practical?

If it is not possible/practical/feasible how would you go about programming your own GUI components that work in JOGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to embedding Swing (or SWT) components within a JOGL canvas, you could use an OpenGL UI toolkit for Java.

You could investigate [FengGUI](http://www.fenggui.org/doku.php).